# Calling Shiny function in Viewer

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

In RStudio, I want a Shiny function `hi.app` to be displayed in the Viewer. The default behaviour is to open the app in the browser.

```
hi.app <- function() {
  require(shiny)
   shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
          textInput("name", "Write your name", value = "stranger"),
          verbatimTextOutput("greeting")
    ),
   server = function(input, output) {
             output$greeting <- renderPrint({
             greeting <- paste("Hi,", input$name)
             greeting
             })
   }
  )
}
hi.app()
```

Once I call `hi.app()`, the app is opened in the browser.

**What I want**: To define a parameter so that this particular app is always opened in RStudio's Viewer when I call it.

**What I have tried** : adding (without success) the following before `shinyApp`:
`options(shiny.launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyWindowViewer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: using `shiny gadgets` instead of `shiny apps` seems infallible for this if the shiny app is meant to be run locally. The parameter con be set via the `viewer` argument in `runGadget(...)`:

```
hi_app <- function() {
  ui = miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget"),
    textInput("name", "Write your name", value = "stranger"),
    verbatimTextOutput("greeting")
  )
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$greeting <- renderPrint({
      greeting <- paste("Hi,", input$name) 
      greeting
    })
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp()
    })
  }
  runGadget(ui, server,viewer = paneViewer())
}

say_hi <- function() {
  library(shiny)
  library(miniUI)
  hi_app()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the options like this

```
hi.app <- function() {
    require(shiny)
    shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(
            textInput("name", "Write your name", value = "stranger"),
            verbatimTextOutput("greeting")
        ),
        server = function(input, output) {
            output$greeting <- renderPrint({
                greeting <- paste("Hi,", input$name)
                greeting
            })
        },
        options=options(shiny.launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyWindowViewer)
    )
}
hi.app()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still launches the browser. Could it be OS-specific? I am running Windows 8, RStudio 0.99.491 and shiny 0.13.1

Comment: It works for me under Windows 7, RStudio 0.99.902 and Shiny 0.13.2. Try restart your R session.

Comment: Restarted and still doesn't work. I wonder if there isn't a deeper configuration issue in my case.